# Get option's value by text

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<select name="dayRange" class="styled">
  <option value="0">All day</option>
  <option value="1">Morning and day (8:00 - 18:00)</option>
  <option value="2">Evening(18:00 - 6:00)</option>
</select>
```

How can I get `value` for specific text?
For example: return `value` for `All Day`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var text = "All day";

var value = $("option").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === text;
}).first().attr("value");
```

Answer (score 7):

Another solution would be to select item like this

```
$('select[name="dayRange"] > option:contains("All Day")').val()
```

you can add this into a function and replace "All Day" by your function parameter.

(just check before calling .val() if your selection is not null)

**Edit:**

The final function would be :

```
getDayRangeValue = function(rangeName) {
    // will return undefined if range doesn't exist.
    return $('select[name="dayRange"] > option:contains("' + rangeName + '")').val();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to browse through them.

```
$("select.styled option").each(function(a,b) {
     if ($(this).html() == "All day") {
        return $(this).val();
     }
});
```

or use .filter()

```
$("select.styled option").filter(function() {
   return $(this).html() == "All day";
}).val();
```